# Large numbers of Hadoop output files

Tags: hadoop

Is there a sensible way, in Hadoop, to write very large numbers of output files? I've been using MultipleOutputs. However, MultipleOutputs allocates a large (~1MB) buffer to each file, so I ran into memory problems.

The ordering of my data is such that in any given reducer, I can write to a target file, close it, then move on to the next one. Unfortunately, MultipleOutputs doesn't expose a method to close a given file. I've written a modified MultipleOutputs which exposes such a method, and deals with the problem, but this doesn't seem ideal.

The alternative would be a final step to split my output into the required files, but I'm not sure of a good way to do this.

Comment: Define "large number", please. What is the functionality that you wish? The number of output files is equal to the number of reducers, so a quick workaround would be to set as many reducers as the desired number of output files.

Comment: I'm reluctant to do that; the outputs are of greatly differing sizes. Essentially, I want to split the output into about a thousand logical units, splitting by a particular id. Using MultipleOutputs as it's supposed to be used, this leads to a thousand outputs per reducer, which I'm okay with, they can be merged later, but because MultipleOutput uses a big buffer per output I run into memory issues. I can alleviate this by hacking MultipleOutput to allow closing of files before the job ends, as my map output is ordered by the id, but this isn't ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Each reducer will generate an output file, more the no. of reducer more the no. of o/p files and lesser the size.

probably you can restrict your no. of reducers.
But make sure limited reducers is optimized.

e.g. if you set reducers=1 then only 1 process has to process all your mapper data hence increases the processing time.